# Assisting Agda's termination checker

Tags: functional-programming, termination, agda

Suppose we define a function

```
f : N \to N
f 0 = 0
f (s n) = f (n/2) -- this / operator is implemented as floored division.
```

Agda will paint f in salmon because it cannot tell if n/2 is smaller than n.  I don't know how to tell Agda's termination checker anything.  I see in the standard library they have a floored division by 2 and a proof that n/2 < n.  However, I still fail to see how to get the termination checker to realize that recursion has been made on a smaller subproblem.

Comment: What about the case where `n = 0`? Anyways, the standard trick to do this stuff is called "well founded recursion"; it's a bit more complicated, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Agda's termination checker only checks for structural recursion (i.e. calls that happen on structurally smaller arguments) and there's no way to establish that certain relation (such as `_<_`) implies that one of the arguments is structurally smaller.

---

Digression: Similar problem happens with positivity checker. Consider the standard fix-point data type:

```
data μ_ (F : Set → Set) : Set where
  fix : F (μ F) → μ F
```

Agda rejects this because `F` may not be positive in its first argument. But we cannot restrict `μ` to only take positive type functions, or show that some particular type function is positive.

---

How do we normally show that a recursive functions terminates? For natural numbers, this is the fact that if the recursive call happens on strictly smaller number, we eventually have to reach zero and the recursion stops; for lists the same holds for its length; for sets we could use the strict subset relation; and so on. Notice that "strictly smaller number" doesn't work for integers.

The property that all these relations share is called well-foundedness. Informally speaking, a relation is well-founded if it doesn't have any infinite descending chains. For example, `<` on natural numbers is well founded, because for any number `n`:

```
n > n - 1 > ... > 2 > 1 > 0
```

That is, the length of such chain is limited by `n + 1`.

`≤` on natural numbers, however, is not well-founded:

```
n ≥ n ≥ ... ≥ n ≥ ...
```

And neither is `<` on integers:

```
n > n - 1 > ... > 1 > 0 > -1 > ...
```

---

Does this help us? It turns out we can encode what it means for a relation to be well-founded in Agda and then use it to implement your function.

For simplicity, I'm going to bake the `_<_` relation into the data type. First of all, we must define what it means for a number to be accessible: `n` is accessible if all `m` such that `m < n` are also accessible. This of course stops at `n = 0`, because there are no `m` so that `m < 0` and this statement holds trivially.

```
data Acc (n : ℕ) : Set where
  acc : (∀ m → m < n → Acc m) → Acc n
```

Now, if we can show that all natural numbers are accessible, then we showed that `<` is well-founded. Why is that so? There must be a finite number of the `acc` constructors (i.e. no infinite descending chain) because Agda won't let us write infinite recursion. Now, it might seem as if we just pushed the problem back one step further, but writing the well-foundedness proof is actually structurally recursive!

So, with that in mind, here's the definition of `<` being well-founded:

```
WF : Set
WF = ∀ n → Acc n
```

And the well-foundedness proof:

```
<-wf : WF
<-wf n = acc (go n)
  where
  go : ∀ n m → m < n → Acc m
  go zero    m       ()
  go (suc n) zero    _         = acc λ _ ()
  go (suc n) (suc m) (s≤s m<n) = acc λ o o<sm → go n o (trans o<sm m<n)
```

Notice that `go` is nicely structurally recursive. `trans` can be imported like this:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary

open DecTotalOrder decTotalOrder
  using (trans)
```

Next, we need a proof that `⌊ n /2⌋ ≤ n`:

```
/2-less : ∀ n → ⌊ n /2⌋ ≤ n
/2-less zero          = z≤n
/2-less (suc zero)    = z≤n
/2-less (suc (suc n)) = s≤s (trans (/2-less n) (right _))
  where
  right : ∀ n → n ≤ suc n
  right zero    = z≤n
  right (suc n) = s≤s (right n)
```

And finally, we can write your `f` function. Notice how it suddenly becomes structurally recursive thanks to `Acc`: the recursive calls happen on arguments with one `acc` constructor peeled off.

```
f : ℕ → ℕ
f n = go _ (<-wf n)
  where
  go : ∀ n → Acc n → ℕ
  go zero    _       = 0
  go (suc n) (acc a) = go ⌊ n /2⌋ (a _ (s≤s (/2-less _)))
```

---

Now, having to work directly with `Acc` isn't very nice. And that's where Dominique's answer comes in. All this stuff I've written here has already been done in the standard library. It is more general (the `Acc` data type is actually parametrized over the relation) and it allows you to just use `<-rec` without having to worry about `Acc`.

---

Taking a more closer look, we are actually pretty close to the generic solution. Let's see what we get when we parametrize over the relation. For simplicity I'm not dealing with universe polymorphism.

A relation on `A` is just a function taking two `A`s and returning `Set` (we could call it binary predicate):

```
Rel : Set → Set₁
Rel A = A → A → Set
```

We can easily generalize `Acc` by changing the hardcoded `_<_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set` to an arbitrary relation over some type `A`:

```
data Acc {A} (_<_ : Rel A) (x : A) : Set where
  acc : (∀ y → y < x → Acc _<_ y) → Acc _<_ x
```

The definition of well-foundedness changes accordingly:

```
WellFounded : ∀ {A} → Rel A → Set
WellFounded _<_ = ∀ x → Acc _<_ x
```

Now, since `Acc` is an inductive data type like any other, we should be able to write its eliminator. For inductive types, this is a fold (much like `foldr` is eliminator for lists) - we tell the eliminator what to do with each constructor case and the eliminator applies this to the whole structure.

In this case, we'll do just fine with the simple variant:

```
foldAccSimple : ∀ {A} {_<_ : Rel A} {R : Set} →
                (∀ x → (∀ y → y < x → R) → R) →
                ∀ z → Acc _<_ z → R
foldAccSimple {R = R} acc′ = go
  where
  go : ∀ z → Acc _ z → R
  go z (acc a) = acc′ z λ y y<z → go y (a y y<z)
```

If we know that `_<_` is well-founded, we can skip the `Acc _<_ z` argument completly, so let's write small convenience wrapper:

```
recSimple : ∀ {A} {_<_ : Rel A} → WellFounded _<_ → {R : Set} →
            (∀ x → (∀ y → y < x → R) → R) →
            A → R
recSimple wf acc′ z = foldAccSimple acc′ z (wf z)
```

And finally:

```
<-wf : WellFounded _<_
<-wf = {- same definition -}

<-rec = recSimple <-wf

f : ℕ → ℕ
f = <-rec go
  where
  go : ∀ n → (∀ m → m < n → ℕ) → ℕ
  go zero    _ = 0
  go (suc n) r = r ⌊ n /2⌋ (s≤s (/2-less _))
```

And indeed, this looks (and works) almost like the one in the standard library!

---

Here's the fully dependent version in case you are wondering:

```
foldAcc : ∀ {A} {_<_ : Rel A} (P : A → Set) →
          (∀ x → (∀ y → y < x → P y) → P x) →
          ∀ z → Acc _<_ z → P z
foldAcc P acc′ = go
  where
  go : ∀ z → Acc _ z → P z
  go _ (acc a) = acc′ _ λ _ y<z → go _ (a _ y<z)

rec : ∀ {A} {_<_ : Rel A} → WellFounded _<_ →
      (P : A → Set) → (∀ x → (∀ y → y < x → P y) → P x) →
      ∀ z → P z
rec wf P acc′ z = foldAcc P acc′ _ (wf z)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why "go" would typecheck, with the exact same type as you have, but <-rec go would fail to typecheck?

Comment: @JonathanGallagher: Which `go` do you mean?

Comment: go : ∀ n → (∀ m → m < n → ℕ) → ℕ

Comment: @JonathanGallagher: Well, if you use `<-rec` I've written, `<-rec go` typechecks just fine. However, if your `<-rec` is the one from the standard library, then it won't typecheck: `<-rec` from `Induction.Nat` has an extra argument and more importantly, it works with `_<′_` rather than `_<_`. You can share your problematic code (via lpaste.net, for example) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: http://lpaste.net/95123

Thanks for the help.  I have a comment in the lpaste link that explains the problem I am having.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher: Here's how I'd do it: http://lpaste.net/95140. If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I won't probably include it in my answer, since it's about "finding the right proof" rather than termination checker itself. If want me to include it, please do let me know.

Comment: I just want to say, if you are reading this answer, the code posted by Vitus is a great example of how to define a function in Agda using well founded recursion.

Answer (score 13):

I would like to offer a slightly different answer than the ones given above. In particular, I want to suggest that instead of trying to somehow convince the termination checker that actually, no, this recursion is perfectly fine, we should instead try to reify the well-founded-ness so that the recursion is manifestly fine in virtue of being structural.

The idea here is that the problem comes from being unable to see that `n / 2` is somehow a "part" of `n`. Structural recursion wants to break a thing into its immediate parts, but the way that `n / 2` is a "part" of `n` is that we drop every other `suc`. But it's not obvious up front how many to drop, we have to look around and try to line things up. What would be nice is if we had some type that had constructors for "multiple" `suc`s.

To make the problem slightly more interesting, let's instead try to define the function that behaves like

```
f : ℕ → ℕ
f 0 = 0
f (suc n) = 1 + (f (n / 2))
```

that is to say, it should be the case that

```
f n = ⌈ log₂ (n + 1) ⌉
```

Now naturally the above definition won't work, for the same reasons your `f` won't. But let's pretend that it did, and let's explore the "path", so to speak, that the argument would take through the natural numbers. Suppose we look at `n = 8`:

```
f 8 = 1 + f 4 = 1 + 1 + f 2 = 1 + 1 + 1 + f 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + f 0 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 4
```

so the "path" is `8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0`. What about, say, 11?

```
f 11 = 1 + f 5 = 1 + 1 + f 2 = ... = 4
```

so the "path" is `11 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0`.

Well naturally what's going on here is that at each step we're either dividing by 2, or subtracting one and dividing by 2. Every naturally number greater than 0 can be decomposed uniquely in this fashion. If it's even, divide by two and proceed, if it's odd, subtract one and divide by two and proceed.

So now we can see exactly what our data type should look like. We need a type that has a constructor that means "twice as many `suc`'s" and another that means "twice as many `suc`'s plus one", as well as of course a constructor that means "zero `suc`s":

```
data Decomp : ℕ → Set where
  zero : Decomp zero
  2*_ : ∀ {n} → Decomp n → Decomp (n * 2)
  2*_+1 : ∀ {n} → Decomp n → Decomp (suc (n * 2))
```

We can now define the function that decomposes a natural number into the `Decomp` that corresponds to it:

```
decomp : (n : ℕ) → Decomp n
decomp zero = zero
decomp (suc n) = decomp n +1
```

It helps to define `+1` for `Decomp`s:

```
_+1 : {n : ℕ} → Decomp n → Decomp (suc n)
zero +1 = 2* zero +1
(2* d) +1 = 2* d +1
(2* d +1) +1 = 2* (d +1)
```

Given a `Decomp`, we can flatten it down into a natural number that ignores the distinctions between `2*_` and `2*_+1`:

```
flatten : {n : ℕ} → Decomp n → ℕ
flatten zero = zero
flatten (2* p) = suc (flatten p)
flatten (2* p +1 = suc (flatten p)
```

And now it's trivial to define `f`:

```
f : ℕ → ℕ
f n = flatten (decomp n)
```

This happily passes the termination checker with no trouble, because we're never actually recursing on the problematic `n / 2`. Instead, we convert the number into a format that directly represents its path through the number space in a structurally recursive way.

***Edit*** It occurred to me only a little while ago that `Decomp` is a little-endian representation of binary numbers. `2*_` is "append 0 to the end/shift left 1 bit" and `2*_+1` is "append 1 to the end/shift left 1 bit and add one". So the above code is really about showing that binary numbers are structurally recursive wrt dividing by 2, which they ought to be! That makes it much easier to understand, I think, but I don't want to change what I wrote already, so we could instead do some renaming here: `Decomp` ~> `Binary`, `2*_` ~> `_,zero`, `2*_+1` ~> `_,one`, `decomp` ~> `natToBin`, `flatten` ~> `countBits`.

Answer (score 9):

After accepting Vitus' answer, I discovered a different way to accomplish the goal of proving a function terminates in Agda, namely using "sized types."  I am providing my answer here because it seems acceptable, and also for critique of any weak points of this answer.

Sized types are described:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4896.pdf

They are implemented in Agda, not only MiniAgda; see here: http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/talkAIM2008Sendai.pdf.

The idea is to augment the data type with a size that allows the typechecker to more easily prove termination.  Size is defined in the standard library.

```
open import Size
```

We define sized natural numbers:

```
data Nat : {i : Size} \to Set where
    zero : {i : Size} \to Nat {\up i} 
    succ : {i : Size} \to Nat {i} \to Nat {\up i}
```

Next, we define predecessor and subtraction (monus):

```
pred : {i : Size} → Nat {i} → Nat {i}
pred .{↑ i} (zero {i}) = zero {i}
pred .{↑ i} (succ {i} n) = n 

sub : {i : Size} → Nat {i} → Nat {∞} → Nat {i}
sub .{↑ i} (zero {i}) n = zero {i}
sub .{↑ i} (succ {i} m) zero = succ {i} m
sub .{↑ i} (succ {i} m) (succ n) = sub {i} m n
```

Now, we may define division via Euclid's algorithm:

```
div : {i : Size} → Nat {i} → Nat → Nat {i}
div .{↑ i} (zero {i}) n = zero {i}
div .{↑ i} (succ {i} m) n = succ {i} (div {i} (sub {i} m n) n)

data ⊥ : Set where
record ⊤ : Set where
notZero :  Nat → Set
notZero zero = ⊥
notZero _ = ⊤
```

We give division for nonzero denominators.
If the denominator is nonzero, then it is of the form, b+1.  We then do
divPos a (b+1) = div a b 
Since div a b returns ceiling (a/(b+1)).

```
divPos : {i : Size} → Nat {i} → (m : Nat) → (notZero m) → Nat {i}
divPos a (succ b) p = div a b
divPos a zero ()
```

As auxiliary:

```
div2 : {i : Size} → Nat {i} → Nat {i}
div2 n = divPos n (succ (succ zero)) (record {})
```

Now we can define a divide and conquer method for computing the n-th Fibonacci number.

```
fibd : {i : Size} → Nat {i} → Nat
fibd zero = zero
fibd (succ zero) = succ zero
fibd (succ (succ zero)) = succ zero
fibd (succ n) with even (succ n)
fibd .{↑ i}  (succ {i} n) | true = 
  let
    -- When m=n+1, the input, is even, we set k = m/2
    -- Note, ceil(m/2) = ceil(n/2)
    k = div2 {i} n
    fib[k-1] = fibd {i} (pred {i} k)
    fib[k] = fibd {i} k
    fib[k+1] =  fib[k-1] + fib[k]
  in
    (fib[k+1] * fib[k]) + (fib[k] * fib[k-1])
fibd .{↑ i} (succ {i} n) | false = 
  let
    -- When m=n+1, the input, is odd, we set k = n/2 = (m-1)/2.
    k = div2 {i} n
    fib[k-1] = fibd {i} (pred {i} k)
    fib[k] = fibd {i} k
    fib[k+1] = fib[k-1] + fib[k]
  in
    (fib[k+1] * fib[k+1]) + (fib[k] * fib[k])
```

Comment: I forgot to mention... for this to work you need to add {-# OPTIONS --sized-types #-} to the top of the file, as sized types are apparently an Agda extension.

Comment: `div` doesn't do the thing you think it does. `div m n` is actually `ceiling(m/(n + 1))`, `div2 3 == 1` and consequently `fibd` produces the sequence `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5, 8, 13...`. But yes, sized types are a cool concept; however, it's very intrusive to data definitions and it's not used much in standard library making it sort of painful to use.

Comment: Yup, it's fine now. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this directly: Agda's termination checker only considers recursion ok on arguments that are *syntactically* smaller.   However, the [Agda standard library](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.StandardLibrary) provides a few modules for proving termination using a well-founded order between the arguments of the functions.  The standard order on natural numbers is such an order and can be used here.

Using the code in Induction.*, you can write your function as follows:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Induction.WellFounded
open import Induction.Nat

s≤′s : ∀ {n m} → n ≤′ m → suc n ≤′ suc m
s≤′s ≤′-refl = ≤′-refl
s≤′s (≤′-step lt) = ≤′-step (s≤′s lt)

proof : ∀ n → ⌊ n /2⌋ ≤′ n
proof 0 = ≤′-refl
proof 1 = ≤′-step (proof zero)
proof (suc (suc n)) = ≤′-step (s≤′s (proof n))

f : ℕ → ℕ
f = <-rec (λ _ → ℕ) helper
  where
    helper : (n : ℕ) → (∀ y → y <′ n → ℕ) → ℕ
    helper 0 rec = 0
    helper (suc n) rec = rec ⌊ n /2⌋ (s≤′s (proof n))
```

I found an article with some explanation [here](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~scm/2008/well-founded-recursion-and-accessibility/). But there may be better references out there.

Comment: That is great thank you!  One thing I would like to know: the second argument of helper is a proof that the value we are recursing on is smaller than the input.  Is this proof generated at runtime on each recursive call, or is it only needed for typechecking, and then discarded at runtime.  If so, this would seem to be a huge performance hit.

Comment: That depends on how you compile the Agda code.  Agda currently compiles code in three ways: (1) to Haskell code, using GHC to compile further, (2) to an intermediate language called Epic and (3) to Javascript code.  In general, the kind of optimisations you are talking about are often possible in theory, but as far as I understand, only the compile path (2) performs them in practice yet. Another DTP languages called Idris, is more advanced in this respect.  Concretely, whether the optimisation would kick in for the _<_ proofs that are passed around, one would have to investigate further...

Comment: I am more confused now.  Your example typechecks just fine.  Now, I have a function, helper, with the exact same type as yours, and I have my helper function typechecking just fine.  However, when I write f = <-rec (\lambda _ \to \bn) helper, I get the error y != suc y.  Any reasons for this?

Comment: Check that it has *exactly* the same type.  I expect the problem is that my helper uses the order <' instead of <, and this is the order that <-rec works with.  This alternative order relation _<'_ is defined in Data.Nat specifically for extra convenience in defining <-rec. It is equivalent to the standard order and the equivalence can be shown with a bit of simple extra work, which should allow you to combine <-rec with your existing helper.

Comment: Here's how you can use the machinery provided by standard library to do just that: http://lpaste.net/95305

Answer (score 3):

A similar question appeared on the Agda mailing-list a few weeks ago and the consensus seemed to be to inject the `Data.Nat` element into `Data.Bin` and then use structural recursion on this representation which is well-suited for the job at hand.

You can find the whole thread here : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.agda/5690

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using well-founded recursion. Let's say you want a function, that applies `⌊_/2⌋` to a number, until it reaches `0`, and collects the results. With the `{-# TERMINATING #-}` pragma it can be defined like this:

```
{-# TERMINATING #-}
⌊_/2⌋s : ℕ -> List ℕ
⌊_/2⌋s 0 = []
⌊_/2⌋s n = n ∷ ⌊ ⌊ n /2⌋ /2⌋s
```

The second clause is equivalent to

```
⌊_/2⌋s n = n ∷ ⌊ n ∸ (n ∸ ⌊ n /2⌋) /2⌋s
```

It's possible to make `⌊_/2⌋s` structurally recursive by inlining this substraction:

```
⌊_/2⌋s : ℕ -> List ℕ
⌊_/2⌋s = go 0 where
  go : ℕ -> ℕ -> List ℕ
  go  _       0      = []
  go  0      (suc n) = suc n ∷ go (n ∸ ⌈ n /2⌉) n
  go (suc i) (suc n) = go i n
```

`go (n ∸ ⌈ n /2⌉) n` is a simplified version of `go (suc n ∸ ⌊ suc n /2⌋ ∸ 1) n`

Some tests:

```
test-5 : ⌊ 5 /2⌋s ≡ 5 ∷ 2 ∷ 1 ∷ []
test-5 = refl

test-25 : ⌊ 25 /2⌋s ≡ 25 ∷ 12 ∷ 6 ∷ 3 ∷ 1 ∷ []
test-25 = refl
```

Now let's say you want a function, that applies `⌊_/2⌋` to a number, until it reaches `0`, and sums the results. It's simply

```
⌊_/2⌋sum : ℕ -> ℕ
⌊ n /2⌋sum = go ⌊ n /2⌋s where
  go : List ℕ -> ℕ
  go  []      = 0
  go (n ∷ ns) = n + go ns
```

So we can just run our recursion on a list, that contains values, produced by the `⌊_/2⌋s` function.

More concise version is

```
⌊ n /2⌋sum = foldr _+_ 0 ⌊ n /2⌋s
```

And back to the well-foundness.

```
open import Function
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Relation.Binary
open import Induction.WellFounded
open import Induction.Nat

calls : ∀ {a b ℓ} {A : Set a} {_<_ : Rel A ℓ} {guarded : A -> Set b}
      -> (f : A -> A)
      -> Well-founded _<_
      -> (∀ {x} -> guarded x -> f x < x)
      -> (∀ x -> Dec (guarded x))
      -> A
      -> List A
calls {A = A} {_<_} f wf smaller dec-guarded x = go (wf x) where
  go : ∀ {x} -> Acc _<_ x -> List A
  go {x} (acc r) with dec-guarded x
  ... | no  _ = []
  ... | yes g = x ∷ go (r (f x) (smaller g))
```

This function does the same as the `⌊_/2⌋s` function, i.e. produces values for recursive calls, but for any function, that satisfies certain conditions.

Look at the definition of `go`. If `x` is not `guarded`, then return `[]`. Otherwise prepend `x` and call `go` on `f x` (we could write `go {x = f x} ...`), which is structurally smaller.

We can redefine `⌊_/2⌋s` in terms of `calls`:

```
⌊_/2⌋s : ℕ -> List ℕ
⌊_/2⌋s = calls {guarded = ?} ⌊_/2⌋ ? ? ?
```

`⌊ n /2⌋s` returns `[]`, only when `n` is `0`, so `guarded = λ n -> n > 0`.

Our well-founded relation is based on `_<′_` and defined in the `Induction.Nat` module as `<-well-founded`.

So we have

```
⌊_/2⌋s = calls {guarded = λ n -> n > 0} ⌊_/2⌋ <-well-founded {!!} {!!}
```

The type of the next hole is `{x : ℕ} → x > 0 → ⌊ x /2⌋ <′ x`

We can easily prove this proposition:

```
open import Data.Nat.Properties

suc-⌊/2⌋-≤′ : ∀ n -> ⌊ suc n /2⌋ ≤′ n
suc-⌊/2⌋-≤′  0      = ≤′-refl
suc-⌊/2⌋-≤′ (suc n) = s≤′s (⌊n/2⌋≤′n n)

>0-⌊/2⌋-<′ : ∀ {n} -> n > 0 -> ⌊ n /2⌋ <′ n
>0-⌊/2⌋-<′ {suc n} (s≤s z≤n) = s≤′s (suc-⌊/2⌋-≤′ n)
```

The type of the last hole is `(x : ℕ) → Dec (x > 0)`, we can fill it by `_≤?_ 1`.

And the final definition is

```
⌊_/2⌋s : ℕ -> List ℕ
⌊_/2⌋s = calls ⌊_/2⌋ <-well-founded >0-⌊/2⌋-<′ (_≤?_ 1)
```

Now you can recurse on a list, produced by `⌊_/2⌋s`, without any termination issues.

Answer (score 0):

---

I encountered this sort of problem when trying to write a quick sort function in Agda.

While other answers seem to explain the problem and solutions more generally, coming from a CS background, I think the following wording would be more accessible for certain readers:

The problem of working with the Agda termination checker comes down to how we can internalize the termination checking process.

Suppose we want to define a function

```
func : Some-Recursively-Defined-Type → A 
func non-recursive-case = some-a 
func (recursive-case n) = some-other-func (func (f n)) (func (g n)) ...
```

In many of the cases, we the writers know `f n` and `g n` are going to be *smaller* than `recursive-case n`. Furthermore, it is not like the proofs for these being *smaller* are super difficult. The problem is more about how we can communicate this knowledge to Agda.

It turns out we can do this by adding a **timer** argument to the definition.

```
Timer : Type
Timer = Nat

measure : Some-Recursively-Defined-Type → Timer
-- this function returns an upper-bound of how many steps left to terminate
-- the estimate should be tight enough for the non-recursive cases that
--    given those estimates, 
--    pattern matching on recursive cases is obviously impossible
measure = {! !}

func-aux : 
  (timer : Timer)        -- the timer, 
  (actual-arguments : Some-Recursively-Defined-Type)
  (timer-bounding : measure actual-arguments ≤ timer)
  → A
func-aux zero non-recursive-case prf = a  
  -- the prf should force args to only pattern match to the non-recursive cases
func-aux (succ t) non-recursive-case prf = a
func-aux (succ t) (recursive-case n) prf = 
  some-other-func (func-aux t (f n) prf') (func-aux t (g n) prf'') ... where 

    prf' : measure (f n) ≤ t
    prf' = {! !}

    prf'' : measure (g n) ≤ t
    prf'' = {! !}
```

With these at hand, we can define the function we want as something like the following :

```
func : Some-Recursively-Defined-Type → A
func x with measure x
func x | n = func-aux n x (≤-is-reflexive n)
```

##### Caveat

1. I have not taken into account anything about whether the computation would be efficient.
2. While `Timer` type is not restricted to be `Nat` (but for all types with which we have a strong enough order relation to work with), I think it is pretty safe to say we don't gain much even if we consider such generality.