# How can i change working of forall in agda?

Tags: agda

I am working with pair of Stream of rationals, Lets say (L,R) Where L and R are Stream of rationals. There are 3 conditions which L and R both have to satisfy to say it is valid. I have written the code as..

```
isCut_ : cut → Set
isCut x = (p q : pair ) → 
              if((((p mem (getLC x)) ∨ (p mem (getRC x)))) ∧ 
                ((not (p mem getLC x)) ∨ (not (p mem getRC x))) ∧ 
                (not (p <pair q) ∨ ((p mem getLC x) ∨ (q mem getRC x))))then ⊤
              else ⊥
```

I really wanted to change the return type of this function to Bool. Here cut means (L, R) and mem is membership.

The problem coming from `forall p q which expect return type to be Set`. 
How should i handle to get desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
isCut : cut → (p q : pair) → Bool
isCut x p q = (((p mem (getLC x)) ∨ (p mem (getRC x))))
            ∧ ((not (p mem getLC x)) ∨ (not (p mem getRC x)))
            ∧ (not (p <pair q) ∨ ((p mem getLC x) ∨ (q mem getRC x))))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But this gives an error `that could not parse because it expect only one argument but getting three. `I just wanted to implement this.. `_plus_ : ℝ → ℝ → cut
          x plus y = if(isCut (getCut x y)) then (getCut x y)
                          else (getCut x y)`                                                        here `(getCut x y) is the cut which i want to pass to isCut to check it is valid or not.` But this is not compiling.

Comment: You need to remove the underscore I had copy-pasted from your post. Or put brackets like so: `(isCut x) p q`.