# How to use Logical AND operation between two sets in agda?

Tags: agda

I wanted to proof that `if there is m which is less than  10 and there is n which is less than 15 then there exist z which is less than 25.`

```
thm : ((∃ λ m → (m < 10)) AND (∃ λ n → (n < 15))) -> (∃ λ z → (z < 25))  
thm = ?
```

How to define AND here?? Please help me. And how to proof this??

Comment: Note that the verb you seek is "prove". The word "proof" is usually used as a noun to describe what you create when you prove something. This is a common error.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem you're trying to prove seems a little strange. In particular, `∃ λ z → z < 25` holds without any assumptions!

Let's do the imports first.

```
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Product
```

**One simple proof of a generalisation of your theorem (without the assumptions) works as follows:**

```
lem : ∃ λ z → z < 25
lem = zero , s≤s z≤n
```

In the standard library, `m < n` is defined as `suc m ≤ n`. The lemma is thus equivalent to `∃ λ z → suc z ≤ suc 24`. For `z = zero` this holds by `s≤s z≤n`.

**Here are a few different ways of expressing your original theorem** (the actual proof is always the same):

```
thm : (∃ λ m → m < 10) × (∃ λ n → n < 15) → ∃ λ z → z < 25
thm _ = lem

thm′ : (∃₂ λ m n → m < 10 × n < 15) → ∃ λ z → z < 25
thm′ _ = lem

thm″ : (∃ λ m → m < 10) → (∃ λ n → n < 15) → ∃ λ z → z < 25
thm″ _ _ = lem
```

I would prefer the last version in most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

`and` corresponds to `product` in Agda. [Here is](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Product.html#439) the corresponding construct in the standard library. In your case, you may want to use [the non-dependent version](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Product.html#1073) `_×_`.