# So: what's the point?

Tags: functional-programming, agda, dependent-type, idris

What is the intended purpose of the [`So`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/base/Data/So.idr#L14) type? Transliterating into Agda:

```
data So : Bool → Set where
  oh : So true
```

`So` lifts a Boolean proposition up to a logical one. Oury and Swierstra's introductory paper [*The Power of Pi*](http://cs.ru.nl/~wouters/Publications/ThePowerOfPi.pdf) gives an example of a relational algebra indexed by the tables' columns. Taking the product of two tables requires that they have different columns, for which they use `So`:

```
Schema = List (String × U)  -- U is the universe of SQL types

-- false iff the schemas share any column names
disjoint : Schema -> Schema -> Bool
disjoint = ...

data RA : Schema → Set where
  -- ...
  Product : ∀ {s s'} → {So (disjoint s s')} → RA s → RA s' → RA (append s s')
```

I'm used to constructing evidence terms for the things I want to prove about my programs. It seems more natural to construct a logical relation on `Schema`s to ensure disjointedness:

```
Disjoint : Rel Schema _
Disjoint s s' = All (λ x -> x ∉ cols s) (cols s')
  where cols = map proj₁
```

`So` seems to have serious disadvantages compared to a "proper" proof-term: pattern matching on `oh` doesn't give you any information with which you could  make another term type-check (Does it?) - which would mean `So` values can't usefully participate in interactive proving. Contrast this with the computational usefulness of `Disjoint`, which is represented as a list of proofs that each column in `s'` doesn't appear in `s`.

I don't really believe that the specification `So (disjoint s s')` is simpler to write than `Disjoint s s'` - you have to define the Boolean `disjoint` function without help from the type-checker - and in any case `Disjoint` pays for itself when you want to manipulate the evidence contained therein.

I am also sceptical that `So` saves effort when you're constructing a `Product`. In order to give a value of `So (disjoint s s')`, you still have to do enough pattern matching on `s` and `s'` to satisfy the type checker that they are in fact disjoint. It seems like a waste to discard the evidence thus generated.

`So` seems unwieldy for both authors and users of code in which it's deployed. 'So', under what circumstances would I want to use `So`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you already have a `b : Bool`, you can turn it into proposition: `So b`, which is a bit shorther than `b ≡ true`. Sometimes (I don't remember any actual case) there is no need to bother with a proper data type, and this quick solution is enough.

> `So` seems to have serious disadvantages compared to a "proper"
>   proof-term: pattern matching on `oh` doesn't give you any information
>   with which you could make another term type-check. As a corollary,
>   `So` values can't usefully participate in interactive proving.
>   Contrast this with the computational usefulness of `Disjoint`, which
>   is represented as a list of proofs that each column in `s'` doesn't
>   appear in `s`.

`So` does give you the same information as `Disjoint` — you just need to extract it. Basically, if there is no inconsistency between `disjoint` and `Disjoint`, then you should be able to write a function `So (disjoint s) -> Disjoint s` using pattern matching, recursion and impossible cases elimination.

However, if you tweak the definition a bit:

```
So : Bool -> Set
So true  = ⊤
So false = ⊥
```

`So` becomes a really useful data type, because `x : So true` immediately reduces to `tt` due to the eta-rule for `⊤`. This allows to use `So` like a constraint: in pseudo-Haskell we could write

```
forall n. (n <=? 3) => Vec A n
```

and if `n` is in canonical form (i.e. `suc (suc (suc ... zero))`), then `n <=? 3` can be checked by the compiler and no proofs are needed. In actual Agda it is

```
∀ {n} {_ : n <=? 3} -> Vec A n
```

I used this trick in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589398/3237465) answer (it is `{_ : False (m ≟ 0)}` there). And I guess it would be impossible to write a usable version of the machinery decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105948/3237465) without this simple definition:

```
Is-just : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> Maybe A -> Set
Is-just = T ∘ isJust
```

where `T` is `So` in the Agda's standard library.

Also, in the presence of instance arguments `So`-as-a-data-type can be used as `So`-as-a-constraint:

```
open import Data.Bool.Base
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Vec

data So : Bool -> Set where
  oh : So true

instance
  oh-instance : So true
  oh-instance = oh

_<=_ : ℕ -> ℕ -> Bool
0     <= m     = true
suc n <= 0     = false
suc n <= suc m = n <= m

vec : ∀ {n} {{_ : So (n <= 3)}} -> Vec ℕ n
vec = replicate 0

ok : Vec ℕ 2
ok = vec

fail : Vec ℕ 4
fail = vec
```

Comment: Also, every proof of "So b" is propositionally equal to any other, which is not necessarily the case for the actual "evidence" of whatever property b is encoding. Sometimes you want that.

Comment: @Saizan, good point. This property is also exploited at the second link in my answer. Do you have some nice use case in mind?

Comment: I feel like there's something deeper here about the relationship between types defined inductively with `data` and those defined recursively in functions. Could you elaborate on why Agda is happy to infer a `So` value with your definition but not with mine?

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson, that's about differences between `data`s and `record`s: the latter have etas, while the former don't. Any inhabitant of `⊤` is definitionally equal to `tt`: `eq : ∀ {x} -> x ≡ tt; eq = refl`, so when Agda meets `_x : ⊤`, where `_x` is a metavariable, `_x` gets instantiated to `tt`, and the unification problem is solved. But when Agda meets `_x : So true`, she can't unify `_x` with something, because this mechanism doesn't work for `data`. But you can force unification using instance arguments, as witnessed above.

Comment: @user3237465 I've used something similar here https://github.com/Saizan/miller/blob/master/Injections/Type.agda#L23 so that prop. equality of Inj corresponds to pointwise equality.

Comment: @Saizan, but inhabitants of `_∉_` are equal propositionally, wouldn't inductive definition give you [the same](http://lpaste.net/143692)? But the `False` part is really a nice use case.

Comment: yeah, False is what makes it interesting there