# Limits of dependent typing in Idris

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, idris

I have been writing Haskell for a while now but wanted to try some experiments with the Idris language, and dependent typing. I have played around a bit, and read the basic doc, however I want to express a certain style of function, and do not know how / if it is possible.

Here are a couple of examples of what I wish to know whether or not can be expressed:

first: a function that takes two natural numbers but only type checks if the first is smaller than the other. So `f : Nat -> Nat -> whatever` where nat1 is smaller than nat2. The idea is that if a called like `f 5 10` it would work, but if I called it like `f 10 5` it would fail to type check.

second: a function that takes a string and a list of strings that only type checks if the first string is in the list of strings.

Are functions like this possible in Idris? If so how would you implement one of the simple examples noted? Thanks!

EDIT:

With the help of several users the following solution functions have been written:

```
module Main

import Data.So

f : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> {auto isLT : So (n < m)} -> Int
f _ _ = 50

g : (x : String) -> (xs : List String) -> {auto inIt : So (elem x xs)} -> Int
g x xs = 52

main : IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ g "hai" ["test", "yo", "ban", "hai", "dog"]
```

These current solutions do not work for large cases. For example if you run f with numbers above a few thousand it takes forever (not literally). I think this is because the type checking is currently search based. One user commented that it is possible to provide a *hint* to auto by writing the proof yourself. Assuming this is what is needed how would one write such a proof for either of these simple cases?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Idris but it is certainly possible. I took a quick glance at the [stdlib](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/tree/master/libs/prelude/Prelude) - the first would be something like `f : (n m : Nat) -> { isLT : Prelude.Nat.LT n m } -> X` and the second `g : (x : String) (xs : List String) -> { in : Prelude.List.elem x xs = True } -> Y`. (where the `=` is propositional equality, not sure the symbol Idris uses for this?) There are perhaps other, better encodings, but these ones work with just the stdlib.

Comment: @user2407038, [it's](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/miscellany.html) `{auto isLT : Prelude.Nat.LT n m}` and `{auto in : Prelude.List.elem x xs = True}`.

Comment: This is great @user2407038 I notice that when I do ```f 50 100``` everything is fine. But when I do ```f 500 1000``` it states that it cannot find a solution. I assume that is because it is brute forcing something? Is there a way to have the same result I want that works for larger numbers?

Comment: @HarpoRoeder When you write `{auto ...}` - according to the very useful link provided by another commenter - "If they have arguments, it will search recursively up to a maximum depth of 100.". You can simply supply the proof yourself, instead of relying on `auto`. `auto` will aso try "Any function with the appropriate return type which is marked with the %hint annotation." so you could try that (still have to write the proof yourself). Again, not too familiar with idris - especially such details.

Comment: @Harpo Roeder, try something like `{auto isLT : So (n < m)}`. More on `So` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270639/so-whats-the-point).

Comment: @user3237465 this one seems to work for larger numbers than the other ones. It takes a while to solve though. I am not familiar with how to write a hint, and the doc does not seem to say much. How would I go about writing a hint so that this is works for more general cases?

Comment: @Harpo Roeder, I don't know about `%hint` stuff. More generally, you can write a predicate `p : SomeType1 -> SomeType2 -> ... -> SomeTypen -> Bool` and use it like this: `{auto satisfies : So (p someValue1 someValue2 ... someValuen)}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[I'm not especially fond of `So`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270639/so-whats-the-point), or indeed of having avoidable proof-terms running around in programs at all. It's more satisfying to weave your expectations into the fabric of the data itself. I'm going to write down a type for "natural numbers smaller than `n`".

```
data Fin : Nat -> Set where
  FZ : Fin (S n)
  FS : Fin n -> Fin (S n)
```

`Fin` is a number-like data type - compare the shape of `FS (FS FZ)` with that of the natural number `S (S Z)` - but with some additional type-level structure. Why's it called `Fin`? There are precisely `n` unique members of the type `Fin n`; `Fin` is thus the family of *finite sets*.

I mean it: `Fin` really is a sort of number.

```
natToFin : (n : Nat) -> Fin (S n)
natToFin Z = FZ
natToFin (S k) = FS (natToFin k)

finToNat : Fin n -> Nat
finToNat FZ = Z
finToNat (FS i) = S (finToNat i)
```

Here's the point: a `Fin n` value must be smaller than its `n`.

```
two : Fin 3
two = FS (FS FZ)
two' : Fin 4
two' = FS (FS FZ)
badTwo : Fin 2
badTwo = FS (FS FZ)  -- Type mismatch between Fin (S n) (Type of FZ) and Fin 0 (Expected type)
```

While we're at it, there aren't any numbers less than zero. That is to say, `Fin Z`, a set with a cardinality of 0, is an empty set.

```
Uninhabited (Fin Z) where
  uninhabited FZ impossible
  uninhabited (FS _) impossible
```

If you have a number that's less than `n`, then it's certainly less than `S n`. We thus have a way of loosening the upper bound on a `Fin`:

```
weaken : Fin n -> Fin (S n)
weaken FZ = FZ
weaken (FS x) = FS (weaken x)
```

We can also go the other way, using the type checker to automatically find the tightest possible bound on a given `Fin`.

```
strengthen : (i : Fin n) -> Fin (S (finToNat i))
strengthen FZ = FZ
strengthen (FS x) = FS (strengthen x)
```

One can safely define subtraction of `Fin` numbers from `Nat` numbers that are larger. We can also express the fact that the result won't be any bigger than the input.

```
(-) : (n : Nat) -> Fin (S n) -> Fin (S n)
n - FZ = natToFin n
(S n) - (FS m) = weaken (n - m)
```

---

That all works, but there's a problem: `weaken` works by rebuilding its argument in O(n) time, and we're applying it at every recursive call of `-`, yielding an O(n^2) algorithm for subtraction. How embarrassing! `weaken` is only really there to help type-checking, but it has a drastic effect on the asymptotic time complexity of the code. Can we get away without weakening the result of the recursive call?

Well, we had to call `weaken` because every time we encounter an `S`, the difference between the result and the bound grows. Instead of forcefully yanking the value up to the correct type, we can close the gap by gently pulling the type down to meet it.

```
(-) : (n : Nat) -> (i : Fin (S n)) -> Fin (S (n `sub` finToNat i))
n - FZ = natToFin n
(S n) - (FS i) = n - i
```

This type is inspired by our success in tightening a `Fin`'s bound with `strengthen`. The bound on the result of `-` is exactly as tight as it needs to be.

`sub`, which I used in the type, is subtraction of natural numbers. The fact that it truncates at zero needn't trouble us, because the type of `-` ensures that it'll never actually happen. (This function can be found in the `Prelude` under the name of `minus`.)

```
sub : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
sub n Z = n
sub Z m = Z
sub (S n) (S m) = sub n m
```

The lesson to be learned here is this. At first, building some correctness properties into our data caused an asymptotic slowdown. We could've given up on making promises about the return value and gone back to an untyped version, but in fact [giving the type checker *more* information](https://allisonmaruska.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/we-need-to-go-deeper.jpg) allowed us to get where we were going without making sacrifices.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry! I didn't realize.

Answer (score 2):

`So` is a very general thing, that allows you to "lift" any boolean condition to the type level. This generality has its price though, which is that such proofs are (at least in my experience) harder to construct and more expensive to compute.

Instead it's usually better to create yourself a specialised proof type, which allows you to express only a certain type of condition, but in a simpler manner, yielding proofs that are cleaner and easier to construct. Idris standard library is full of such specialized proof types (or rather type families). Sure enough, it already contains those that you're concerned about here.

```
||| Proofs that `n` is less than or equal to `m`
||| @ n the smaller number
||| @ m the larger number
data LTE  : (n, m : Nat) -> Type where
  ||| Zero is the smallest Nat
  LTEZero : LTE Z    right
  ||| If n <= m, then n + 1 <= m + 1
  LTESucc : LTE left right -> LTE (S left) (S right)
```

(from `Prelude.Nat`)

A term of type `LTE x y` represents a proof that `x` is not larger than `y` (note that it works only for `Nat`s, because it relies on the very internal structure of that type). `LTEZero` does not require any arguments since `Z` is never larger than any `Nat` (including `Z` itself). You are free to construct such proofs at will. For other numbers you can prove the `LTE` relation by induction (given the rule that `LTE x y` implies `LTE (S x) (S y)`). By deconstructing your arguments, you'll finally arrive at a moment when one of them is `Z`. If it's the left one, then you're done by stating that `Z` is less than or equal anything, if it's the right one, sorry, your assumption was false and therefore you won't be able to construct your proof.

```
maybeLTE : (n, m : Nat) -> Maybe (LTE n m)
maybeLTE Z _ = Just LTEZero
maybeLTE _ Z = Nothing
maybeLTE (S n) (S m) = map LTESucc $ maybeLTE n m
```

Note how this construction does not rely on any external notion of ordering. Instead, this very type *defines* what does it mean for a `Nat` to be less than or equal to another `Nat`. The two constructors (along with the type `Nat` itself) can be thought of as axioms of a theory, from which you can derive your proofs. Let's look at the types of these constructors again:

`LTEZero : LTE Z right` states that `Z` is less than or equal to `right` *for all* `right`s.

`LTESucc : LTE left right -> LTE (S left) (S right)` represents an implication: if `left` is less than or equal to `right` then `S left` is less than or equal to `S right`.

This is Curry-Howard Isomorphism in full glory.