# In Idris, how do I extract a proof from a So type?

Tags: dependent-type, idris, proof-of-correctness

If I have a `So` type, like `So (x < y)`, created by something like

```
IsLt : Ord a => (x: a) -> (y: a) -> Type
IsLt x y = So (x < y)
```

How can I extract the proof of `(x < y)` out of this? I can't find a function in the standard library for this.

`So` is defined in the standard library as:

```
data So : Bool -> Type where 
    Oh : So True
```

And I'm not sure how to extract the proof from that, for use in proving something like:

```
ltNeNat : {x: Nat} -> {y: Nat} -> So (x < y) -> Not (x = y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove the lemma by induction on `x`:

```
ltNeNat : {x: Nat} -> {y: Nat} -> So (lt x y) -> Not (x = y)
ltNeNat {x = Z} {y = Z} Oh _ impossible
ltNeNat {x = Z} {y = S _} _ Refl impossible
ltNeNat {x = S x} {y = Z} so Refl impossible
ltNeNat {x = S x} {y = S y} so eq =
  let IH = ltNeNat {x} {y} so in
  IH $ succInjective _ _ eq
```

I had to replace `<` with `lt` because otherwise Idris couldn't see that `So (S x < S y)` and `So (x < y)` are definitionally equal.

Observe that I used information encoded in `So` in the first and the last clauses.

Comment: That's true. I'm stucked at proving `S x < S y = True -> x < y = True` because booleans don't really help to prove things.

Comment: You need to "reflect" booleans into propositions. ssreflect (of Coq ecosystem) uses it extensively. This way you get to use logic and computations -- this is very useful when dealing with decidable propositions.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you can't extract proof from boolean value. `So` is weak type. It's should be used only to guarantee performance of some checks at runtime. Also see this question:

[So: what's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270639/so-whats-the-point)

I'm not sure it's not possible. But I tried to prove `ltNeNat` and failed miserably. Though, maybe I'm just stupid. Consider using some evidence instead of `So`, like `Refl`. Pattern matching on `So` doesn't give you more power that helps proving things. You can find valid use cases of `So` under [this tutorial](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/93772df08ddf57a515b75eb43b8d4e8850a8fbec/docs/effects/simpleeff.rst#example). Even if you're able to extract proofs from `So` it requires a lot of code from you and dealing with `So` is less convenient.