# How to go from an explicit proof of size decrease to a halting reduction algorithm?

Tags: agda

Suppose I have:

- A `Linear : Set` type for linear λ-calculus terms.
- A `reduce-once : Term → Term` function that performs a global reduction of redexes.
- A `size : Linear → Nat` relation that counts the number of constructors.
- A proof `reduce-once-halts : (t : Linear) → size (reduce-once t) < size t`.

That is, I have a proof that applying `reduce-once` always decreases the size of a term. From that, one should logically be able to implement a terminating function, `reduce : (t : Linear) → Sigma t IsNormalized`, that reduces the term to normal form. Since I believe this is a common situation, my question is: how is that usually formalized in Agda? How can I convince it that a function that decreases the size of its argument can be applied recursively and will eventually halt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assisting Agda's termination checker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19642921/3237465).

Comment: Are `Linear` and `Term` meant to be the same type here? If so, I think your current hypotheses are impossible. If `reduce-once` is always applicable and always makes size smaller you get an infinite descending chain of `Nat`s. Which is impossible since `Nat` with the usual ordering is well-founded.

Comment: @Potato44 yes, that was a typo. Also sorry, I forgot to add a `Not(HasRedex t)` argument; the actual code is [here](https://github.com/moonad/Formality-Agda/blob/master/Formality.agda) just in case I have any further typo (`reduce-once-halts` is called `reduce<`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<-rec` from the `Data.Nat.Induction` module to do well-founded induction over `_<_`. In this case, one solution is to do induction on the predicate "terms of size strictly less than n can be reduced":

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Induction
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate
  Term : Set
  reduce-once : Term → Term
  size : Term → ℕ
  reduce-once-halts : (t : Term) → size (reduce-once t) < size t

reduce-aux : (n : ℕ) (t : Term) → size t < n → Term
reduce-aux = <-rec
  (λ n → (t : Term) → size t < n → Term)
  λ n h t size-t<n → h (size t) size-t<n (reduce-once t) (reduce-once-halts t)

reduce : Term → Term
reduce t = reduce-aux (1 + size t) t ≤-refl
```